# Very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04 (no changes made prior to this)

Tags: boot, 18.04, snap

Without making changes to my system, this morning it started booting very slowly. The laptop is a Toshiba Portege Z835 (intel graphics card + SSD):

`systemd-analyze blame`:

```
5min 42.155s plymouth-quit-wait.service
5min 29.705s docker.service
 4min 7.502s snapd.seeded.service
 1min 6.244s snapd.service
      7.706s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.965s dev-sda1.device
      4.093s dev-loop0.device
      4.086s dev-loop2.device
      4.071s dev-loop1.device
      4.055s dev-loop3.device
      4.025s dev-loop4.device
      4.004s dev-loop7.device
      3.972s dev-loop5.device
      3.951s dev-loop8.device
      3.941s dev-loop6.device
      3.938s dev-loop9.device
      3.911s postgresql@10-main.service
      3.034s plymouth-start.service
      2.989s postgresql@9.6-main.service
      2.160s systemd-journal-flush.service
      1.677s networkd-dispatcher.service
      1.474s ModemManager.service
      1.175s systemd-udevd.service
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
graphical.target @5min 49.849s
└─multi-user.target @5min 49.849s
  └─docker.service @15.389s +5min 29.705s
    └─network-online.target @15.374s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @7.666s +7.706s
        └─NetworkManager.service @6.861s +787ms
          └─dbus.service @6.485s
            └─basic.target @6.386s
              └─sockets.target @6.385s
                └─snapd.socket @6.376s +8ms
                  └─sysinit.target @6.369s
                    └─apparmor.service @5.714s +654ms
                      └─local-fs.target @5.712s
                        └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @16.031s
                          └─run-snapd-ns.mount @15.564s
                            └─swap.target @5.397s
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4aa4cb84\x2d97ff\x2d4a32\x2d
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4aa4cb84\x2d97ff\x2d4a32\x
```

I tried removing `docker-ce` with `apt-get purge` but then `snapd` takes 5-6 minutes when booting.

I searched for possible explanations and solutions and checked the following:

- I checked the swap partition UUID and it seems fine
- Tried uncommenting `#WaylandEnable=false` in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, but no change in boot time
- Tried removing Snap and Docker from Startup Applications (so they won't autostart on boot) but no change either

Not sure what else to try. A reboot takes between 2 and 8 minutes now. It used to be around 10-15 seconds.

**Update:** as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051882/721271), a temporary workaround is to move the mouse or touchpad while loading. I believe a bug report was also created: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1779872

Comment: I faced a similar situation with Mint 19. Kernel 4.15.0-24 works totally fine as long as I do not install docker-ce.
Downgrading to 4.15.0-23 solved this issue.
systemd-analyze blame: 1.598s docker.service
Another installation with kernel 4.15.0-24 works fine with docker. That installation does not use luks+lvm for harddisk encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact issue on kernel 4.15.0-24 ... It started immediatelly after the update and reboot, so I guess there is something wrong with the kernel. Reverting to the previous kernel (4.15.0-23) fixed it for me.

Comment: This is another workaround that seems to work in my case.
But, there is more info on the actual problem here (relating to Snap): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o