# Kubuntu 19.04 stuck with “Started waiting until snapd is fully seeded” for nearly 10 minutes

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 19.04

```
$ journalctl -u snapd.seeded.service --since today

-- Reboot --
jul 19 10:29:22 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 10:29:22 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 10:41:41 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 10:41:41 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 10:43:04 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 10:43:04 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 10:48:26 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 10:48:26 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 10:50:36 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 10:50:36 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 10:52:05 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 10:52:05 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 10:53:43 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 10:53:43 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 10:54:46 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 10:54:46 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 10:58:07 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 10:58:07 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 11:11:38 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 11:11:38 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
- Reboot --
jul 19 11:25:49 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 11:25:49 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 11:32:03 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 11:32:03 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 10:58:07 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 10:58:07 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 11:11:38 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 11:11:38 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 11:14:41 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 11:14:41 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 11:20:14 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 11:20:14 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 11:25:49 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 11:25:49 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 11:32:03 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 11:32:03 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
-- Reboot --
jul 19 11:37:40 pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
jul 19 11:37:40 pc systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
jul 19 11:40:27 pc systemd[1]: snapd.seeded.service: Succeeded.
jul 19 11:40:27 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o