# Booting time lin ubuntu

Tags: boot, time

My PC, which is running Ubuntu, takes a long time to boot.

Here are the outputs of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 48.620s
└─multi-user.target @1min 48.620s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @1min 31.009s +589ms
    └─snapd.service @1min 2.833s +28.172s
      └─basic.target @1min 1.943s
        └─sockets.target @1min 1.943s
          └─snapd.socket @1min 1.883s +59ms
            └─sysinit.target @1min 1.857s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @52.628s +879ms
                └─apparmor.service @13.266s +39.359s
                  └─local-fs.target @13.167s
                    └─run-user-1000-doc.mount @1min 44.431s
                      └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 25.766s
                        └─local-fs-pre.target @8.072s
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @7.695s +375ms
                            └─systemd-sysusers.service @6.889s +805ms
                              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @6.412s +282ms
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @6.288s
                                  └─system.slice @6.225s
                                    └─-.slice @6.225s
```

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
         51.958s dev-sda1.device
         39.426s dev-loop37.device
         39.398s dev-loop31.device
         39.359s apparmor.service
         39.320s dev-loop32.device
         39.176s dev-loop40.device
         38.205s dev-loop30.device
         38.139s dev-loop35.device
         38.127s dev-loop8.device
         37.854s dev-loop21.device
         37.673s dev-loop36.device
         37.661s dev-loop13.device
         37.315s dev-loop27.device
         37.280s dev-loop29.device
         36.984s dev-loop9.device
         36.664s dev-loop17.device
         36.301s dev-loop15.device
         36.279s dev-loop28.device
         35.967s dev-loop34.device
         35.500s dev-loop3.device
         34.508s dev-loop38.device
         34.502s dev-loop42.device
         34.486s dev-loop43.device
lines 1-23
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame`? What GPU do you have? What are your system specs? Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am a nobi to linux can you tell me how to find the terms mentioned by u above

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 i5 processor 2gb ram

Comment: Open a terminal. Then give these two commands one by one, and edit the question to paste the output

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how long it's taking to reach your "graphical.target", Do this, even though it was written at the time of Ubuntu 18.04. It works, even Ubuntu 20.04 (There are two methods; use one or both):

Method One

Type (in the terminal):

```
$ sudo sed -e 's/^RESUME=/#RESUME=/g' \
     -i /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

After that is finished, type:

```
$ echo "RESUME=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--YOUR FLAVOR OF UBUNTU (eg. mate)--vg-swap_1" | \
  sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

Recreate initrd and reboot system.

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

After that is finished, type:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

The kernel boot time should be faster. Verify by typing:

```
$ systemd-analyze
```

You will also be able to use hibernation after this.

Method Two

Navigate to /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/

Right click on "resume" and choose "Edit as Administrator".
Change the line:

RESUME=UUID=WHATEVER YOUT NUMBER IS
(ex - RESUME=UUID=67b3fe6f-1ec4-413f-8c5a-1136bc7f3270)

To:

RESUME=none

Now open a terminal and type:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

After that is finished, type:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

The boot time should be quicker.

Taken from: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037457/slow-boot-with-ssd-and-lvm-on-new-install-of-18-04) and [here](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/01/ubuntu-1804-lvm-swap-wait-for-root-en/).