# How does /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume work?

Tags: boot

I had a slow boot problem in 18.04 with a new NUC 7i5 equipped with an nvm ssd, which I traced down with dmesg and fixed with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029598/xubuntu-18-04-kernel-takes-long-to-boot) answer, but, I'm curious: what's really going on in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume ?  It is clearly concerned with swap partitions, but, how?  And, how does removing a specific UUID reference improve boot time performance so dramatically?

Answer (score 5):

When there's a device referenced by UUID there then the system is waiting for that device before it can resume, because it needs the data stored on it. If the device doesn't exist then the system is going through every way of finding a device, and waiting, so as to be sure the device doesn't exist before it fails-over to a normal boot.

The link to swap is that the swap partition is used to store the memory contents in order to retrieve them and perform the resume operation.

You can check if swap is loaded with `swapon --show` and if swap is configured correctly by comparing `blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab | grep swap`.

Logical volumes (`man lvm`, `sudo lvdisplay`) can complicate the swap situation too.